# Save images in S3 from React SPA with express backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I have a React component where I ask the user to insert an image using react-dropze. On drop, I save the image into an image state.
Like this:

```
const handleOnDrop = (files) => {
    setimage(files[0]);
}
```

Once I submit, I send a request to my back-end in order to get the URL with this function:

```
export const generateUploadURL = async () => {
    const rawBytes = await randomBytes(16);
    const imageName =  rawBytes.toString('hex');

    const params = ({
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: imageName,
        ContentType: 'image/*',
        Expires: 60
    })

    const uploadUrl = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params);
    return uploadUrl;
}
```

I get the URL and finally execute a put into the s3 with the URL:

```
await axios.put(url, {
   headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
   },
   body: image
});
```

And then I save the data into my database but that's not important.
The thing is, after that, I can't render the image from the link I stored so I went into the link and encountered this:

```
{"headers":{"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"},"body":{"path":"asdasdsadtest.jpg"}}
```

I tried setting the content-type to the imageType but that didn't work either. I have no clue on how I could make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject ") api? Using s3.upload would allow you to send the file in one go and would make it much simpler in my opinion. See: https://stackabuse.com/uploading-files-to-aws-s3-with-node-js/ for an example of this solution

Comment: Because I'm letting the user upload from the front-end but with certain validations, so I get from the back-end the SignedUrlPromise and then send the url to the front-end in order to upload the file directly.
If I understood correctly, in order to use the upload I would have to send the file to the back-end first.

Comment: Unless you have very strict control over what will be uploaded I would advise against uploading from the frontend, if a malicious user can upload something other than the file you validated that could lead to serious damage . You should do at least some md5 check on the file

Comment: Being honest with you, that makes a lot of sense and probably is better to consume double for files that are uploaded than getting a virus. Will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it the following way:

```
url = await getS3Url(image);
await axios.put(url, image, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": image.type
  }
});
```

Insted of placing it into the body, this worked.